# Size of intersection of U complement with C complement

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am currently doing a Discrete Maths module and one of the questions given was:

[image: Venn Diagram]

Find the number of elements in $\left(A^c \cup B^c\right)^c$ intersection with $C^c$ if the above diagram represents the number of elements in each set

$\cdot^c$ is the complement

---

The way I understand it is that $A^c \cup B^c$ is just $U$ so $U$ complement intersection with anything should be zero (or phi). But the website says that that answer is incorrect.

Comment: A complement union B complement is U (I believe so at least). And the complement of that is U complement. See edit

Comment: $A^c \cup B^c = (A \cap B)^c$, not $U$.

Comment: Oh, I see it now! Thank you.